# XML model binding fails in ASP.net WebApi2 after a time

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have several webapi micro services hosted in TopShelf containers which accept and reply with JSON and XML formatters. **After running for a time, the XML formatter stops** binding the XML request data to the model. Passing **JSON or Form-Data still works**. Specifying an `Accept: application/xml` header which results in an XML response. Replaying the failed XML requests after **restarting the service returns the expected responses**.

The root cause of the problem is that the `SupportedMediaTypes` property of the XmlFormatter gets cleared at some point while the service is running and the model binding fails.

**How can I find what is clearing the `SupportedMediaTypes`?**

---

Notes while investigating the problem follow.

<strike>I cannot replicate the problem in any environments which I can connect a debugger to.</strike>

One of the services started failing while I was debugging locally. From what I can see, it is picking the DataContractSerializer rather than the XmlSerializer for deserialization.

The Startup class adds the formatters in this order:

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new RecordSetMediaTypeFormatter<RecordAssociation>());
config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerializer = true });
config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerializer = false });
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Checking the formatter order in HttpConfiguration shows that the XmlSerializer formatter has priority:

```
> actionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters
Count = 4
    [0]: {API.Formatters.RecordSetMediaTypeFormatter<API.Contract.DataObjects.RecordAssociation>}
    [1]: {System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter}
    [2]: {System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter}
    [3]: {System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter}
> (actionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters[1] as System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter).UseXmlSerializer
true
> (actionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters[2] as System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter).UseXmlSerializer
false
```

The `UseXmlSerializer == true` formatter indicates that it can read the type, but the `UseXmlSerializer == false` formatter is selected by the collection, even with `System.Object`:

```
> actionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters[1].CanReadType(typeof(System.Object))
true
> (actionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters.FindReader(typeof(System.Object), System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml")) as System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter).UseXmlSerializer
false
```

<strike>Why does the `MediaTypeFormatterCollection.FindReader` method return the lower priority formatter?</strike>

Checking the source for `MediaTypeFormatterCollection` on GitHub (thanks Microsoft!), I thought to look at the `SupportedMediaTypes` for both instances:

```
> actionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters[1].SupportedMediaTypes
Count = 0
> actionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters[2].SupportedMediaTypes
Count = 2
    [0]: {application/xml}
    [1]: {text/xml}
```

On a restart of the project, the collection for Formatters[1] is the same as for Formatters[2].

The only references to the `MediaTypeFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes` property in the project is where the `RecordSetMediaTypeFormatter` sets its own `SupportedMediaTypes` in its constructor.

What is clearing the XmlFormatter's `SupportedMediaTypes` property at run-time?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find the what was the issue here. Want to know why two formatters of same type with true/false values were added

Comment: I believe I eventually traced the problem to a third party library cleared the property when a particular class was loaded. I just used a different library for that functionality. I'll have to check source control when I get a chance to see if I can find what the library was.